# Is there any way to implicitly convert parameters in template functions

Tags: c++

I'm using [lazy_importer](https://github.com/JustasMasiulis/lazy_importer) recently but I get a strange error when calling functions; for example:

```
LI_FN(WriteFile)(DiskHandle, Sector, sizeof(Sector), &Bytes, NULL);
```

I get this error:

> C2664,Cannot convert parameter 5 from '_Ty' to 'LPOVERLAPPED'

The below code fixes this:

```
LI_FN(WriteFile)(DiskHandle, Sector, sizeof(Sector), &Bytes, (LPOVERLAPPED)NULL);
```

I was wondering if I could be **more lazy** and not add the `(LPOVERLAPPED)` manually, but **let the compiler do it for me**?

Comment: Do you get an error even if you use `nullptr` instead of `NULL` ?

Comment: no error any more,thanks,but i got warnings,it made me uncomfortable```Data may be lost when converting from "size_t" to "DWORD"```

Comment: That's because `sizeof` expresses to `size_t`, and [`WriteFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-writefile) expects a `DWORD` for that argument. It's a separate issue.

Comment: What's `LI_FN`?

Comment: @Peter [a macro from lazy-importer](https://github.com/JustasMasiulis/lazy_importer).

Comment: @WhozCraig i know that,how can i fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occurs because of your use of the `NULL` token, which is basically a **C** language macro for a null pointer. [Relevant cppreference page.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL)

Typically, for a C compilation, `NULL` is defined as a `void*` pointer with a value of zero, like this (the *exact* definition can vary between compilers and platforms, but the C Standard *requires* that `NULL` be defined as a "null pointer constant"):

```c
#define NULL ((void *)0)
```

However, in C++, `NULL` is generally defined as an ***integer*** literal (although the C++ Standard does allow it to be defined as `nullptr`):

```cpp
#define NULL 0
```

Thus, there is no implicit conversion from `NULL` to a pointer type and, if you use that token, you need to add an explicit cast to a pointer.

In C++ programs, you should really be using the [in-built `nullptr` literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) when initialising pointers to a null value, or passing null pointer arguments. This *is* implicitly convertible to a null pointer of any type.